# QR Scanning in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Hey!**
I am wishing to create an app with a QR scanner.
Do anyone have any idea how to add a QR scanner to my Xamarin.Forms project?

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of NuGet packages to use even with Xamarin.Forms take a look at some:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/scandit

https://blog.xamarin.com/barcode-scanning-made-easy-with-zxing-net-for-xamarin-forms/

https://github.com/vulcanlee/xamarin-forms-develop-notes-example/tree/master/XFScan

https://components.xamarin.com/view/MWBarcodeScanner

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite : 
Zxing Barcode Scanning Library for MonoTouch, Mono for Android, and Windows Phone :

**https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile**

tutorial here if you wish :

**https://julianocustodio.com/2017/11/03/scanner/**